# xlrd и openpyxl извлекают неправильные значения ячеек (Excel)

Tags: python

Нужно считать значения из определенных ячеек таблицы и сложить их, никак не получается сделать. Сначала думал, что-то не так в модуле (openpyxl постоянно апгрейдят - думал, где-то не уследил за новшествами), но модуль xlrd выдает точно такие же ошибки!

Вот код:

```
import xlrd, xlwt
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(r"E:\Projects_working (11).xlsx")
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name('Language Process')
for i in range(1, 100):
    cellVal = sheet.cell(i, 14).value   #нужно найти "5" в 14-м столбце
    if type(cellVal) == float and cellVal == 5.0: #нужно узнать соответств.
        print(sheet.cell(i, 11).value)            #значения в 11-м столбце
```

И вот, например, вместо 22 код выдает 42782.61458. (Остальные значения тоже похожи: 42782.66146, 42781.38542, 42781.42708, 42781.625 и т.д.)

Сначала я использовал модуль openpyxl. В нем я пришел к такому результату после добавления флага data_only=True при загрузке книги: `wb = load_workbook("file.xlsx", data_only=True)`. Если же этот парам не использовать, то код выдает странные формулы: =B32+((M32-B32)/2), =B41+((M41-B41)/2) и т.д.

```
import openpyxl
wb =  openpyxl.load_workbook(r"E:\Projects_working (11).xlsx")
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Language Process')
for i in range(1, 100):
    cellVal = sheet.cell(row=i, column=14).value
    if type(cellVal) == float and cellVal == 5.0:
        print(sheet.cell(row=i, column=11).value)
```

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться Pandas модулем: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-excel-reader

Comment: [Я случайно создал две учетных записи, как их объединить?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Выложите ваш excel файл на какой-нибудь файлообменник, так, чтобы можно было воспроизвести эту проблему...